# Typescript Function returns before promise.all finishes

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise, promise.all

I have a code as follow

```
export class MyHandler {
    entry = async (data: string[]): Promise<Map<string, string>> {
        const response: Map<string, string> = new Map();
        Promise.all(
            data.map(async (item) => {
                const apiGetDataRequest = {
                    data: item
                };
                const apiGetDataResponse = await this.client.apiCall(apiGetDataRequest);
                return apiGetDataResponse.data;
            });
        ).then((results) => {
            for (const result of results) {
                const value = myFirstMethod([1, 2, 3]);
                response.set(result, value);
            }
        });

        return response;
    };

    myFirstMethod = (items: number[]): string {
        const result = mySecondMethod(items, 'Test');
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    };

    mySecondFunction = (items: number[]): string {
        let finalResult = "";
        Promise.all(
            items.map(async (item) => {
                const apiCallRequest = {
                    data: item
                };
                const apiCallResponse = await this.client.apiCall(apiCallRequest);
                return apiCallResponse.data;
            });
        ).then((results) => {
            for (const result of results) {
                finalResult = finalResult + ', ' + result;
            }
        });

        return finalResult;
    };
}
```

The issue that I'm running into is that `mySecondFunction` returns before all promises are done and as the result, `result` in `myFirstMethod` always has a empty string value.

How can I have `mySecondFunction` to wait for all promises before returning?

Answer (score 1):

Your `mySecondFunction` method is synchronous, you will need to `await` on `Promise.all`.

```
mySecondFunction = async (items: number[]): string {
    let finalResult = "";
    await Promise.all(
        items.map(async (item) => {
            const apiCallRequest = {
                data: item
            };
            const apiCallResponse = await this.client.apiCall(apiCallRequest);
            return apiCallResponse.data;
        });
    ).then((results) => {
        for (const result of results) {
            finalResult = finalResult + ', ' + result;
        }
    });

    return finalResult;
};
```

Comment: adding `await` in front of `Promise.all` give me the following error: `TS1308: 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.`

Comment: see my edit, make your method `async` !

Comment: Thank you, if I do that, I need to change the return type from `string` to `Promise<string>`. This will cause an issue because if the same `item` exists in `data` twice in `entry` function, the result will not be predictable.

Comment: Inside `myFirstMethod` I will have `mySecondMethod(items, 'Test').then((r) => {result = r});`

Comment: Now since I have 2 same `item` in `data` in `entry` function, the result of one can override the other

Comment: If your method has async logic, then it returns a promise, and you have to deal with it as an async response. Period. There's no work around for that because your code needs to be able to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Though [Matthieu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75539173/1426891) is correct, you can also make this same upgrade to `mySecondFunction` without using `async`. This is because `async` is just [syntactic sugar for a function that returns a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). That would look like this:

```js
// not async
mySecondFunction = (items: number[]): string {
    // Return the chained promise.
    return Promise.all(
        items.map(async (item) => {
            const apiCallRequest = {
                data: item
            };
            const apiCallResponse = await this.client.apiCall(apiCallRequest);
            return apiCallResponse.data;
        })
    ).then((results) => {
        // Style nit: Move the definition of finalResult closer to its use.
        let finalResult = "";
        for (const result of results) {
            finalResult = finalResult + ', ' + result;
        }
        // Return finalResult within the promise chain, so this becomes
        // the result of the Promise the function returns.
        return finalResult;
    });
};
```

If you're in an environment that supports `async`/`await`—and you are, because you're doing so within `map`—then there's not much reason to prefer this over the other style. That said, much of the value of `async` is to avoid explicit promise chains with `then`, and you still have one in your code. You may find your code easier to read if you avoid mixing styles.

```js
mySecondFunction = async (items: number[]): string {
    let finalResult = "";
    let results = await Promise.all(
        items.map(async (item) => {
            const apiCallRequest = {
                data: item
            };
            const apiCallResponse = await this.client.apiCall(apiCallRequest);
            return apiCallResponse.data;
        })
    );

    // Instead of putting this in a `then` method,
    // just use the results you've awaited above.
    for (const result of results) {
        finalResult = finalResult + ', ' + result;
    }

    return finalResult;
};
```

(With either style, you'll need to change `myFirstMethod` to `await` the result of `mySecondFunction` and also change your `entry` function to ensure it is awaiting the result of `myFirstMethod`. Such is the nature of asynchronous code: you have to wait for everything you depend on.)